# Symfony2 add extra selectbox

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I added extra select box `(choice type)` and `mapped=>false` see the code below.
However when I submit the form. It returned the error msg `"This value is not valid."`

```
 $form->add('extraField' ,'choice', array(
            'required' => false,
            'choices' => $arrayChoices,
            'mapped'=>false, 
            'data' =>$id
            ));
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the value of $arrayChoices ?

Comment: @Jahnux73 `$arrayChoices = array(1=>'choice1', 2=>'choice2');`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after this doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices

I don't see 'data' option. Try to remove it please. (and , what is the use of this field [data]? )

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `$id` is  valid array key for `$arrayChoices`?

Also, when you submit the form, the request must contain a valid key inside of `$arrayChoices`

Comment: the `$id` is exists in DB. Following is the error msg out:

`object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)[2621]
  private 'message' => string 'This value is not valid.' (length=24)
  protected 'messageTemplate' => string 'This value is not valid.' (length=24)
  protected 'messageParameters' => 
    array (size=1)
      '{{ value }}' => string '28' (length=2)
  protected 'messagePluralization' => null`